# Qt C++ Отдельный лог qDebug в файл для каждого потока - как реализовать?

Tags: c++, qt, логирование

Мне необходимо реализовать вывод `qDebug()` в разные файлы для всех потоков. То есть, для каждого потока свой текстовый файл.

Знаю, что сначала необходимо реализовать

```
void messageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &message)
```

Реализация многопоточности унаследована от `QThread`. Переопределён метод `run()`.

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как определить, какой именно поток вызвал `qDebug()`, и поэтому в какой именно файл писать полученное сообщение - непонятно.

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов вашего перехватчика сообщений осуществляется в том потоке, в котором произошел вызов qDebug() без дополнительной синхронизации. Поэтому достаточно запросить ID текущего потока изнутри messageHandler.

```
QFile& outSteamsByThreadId()
{
    static std::map< Qt::HANDLE, QFile> ret;
    static QMutex m;
    QMutexLocker locker(&m);
    return ret[QThread::currentThreadId()];
}

void messageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &message)
{
    QFile& out = outSteamsByThreadId();
    if(!out.isOpen())
        out.open( ... );

    std::cout<< ... ;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 0):

При помощи конструктора [QDebug::QDebug(QIODevice *device)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#QDebug) создайте отдельный QDebug для каждого потока и работайте с ним.

```
class SomeThread {

    void run() {          
        QString filename = "thread1.log";
        QFile file(filename);
        if(!file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append)){
            // Проблемы с созданием файла
        } else {
            QDebug log(file);
            log << "запись";
            ...
        }   
    }

}
```